# How to change the function of cost of osm2po?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

As the column 'kmh' shows speed limits wrong for my city, and I didn't want to modify the configuration file of osm2po for each type of road, is there a way to change the cost function? I wish:

cost= length

and not

cost= length/kmh

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question with `pgrouting` I assume you want to use osm2po to generate the PostgreSQL tables. So why don't you update your database table after import?

```
UPDATE <table> SET cost = ST_Length(geom_way);
```

And if you prefer the length in unit meter, then you can transform the geometry into some Mercator projection:

```
UPDATE <table> SET cost = ST_Length(ST_Transform(geom_way,3857));
```

Comment: No, it is not possible because the query to calculate the shortest path between two point (pg routing) uses cost and reverse_cost. If I modify only the cost column  the query will not be correct. Also I can't change the column reverse_cost in the same way!

Answer (score 1):

or just

```
UPDATE <table> SET cost = km
```

and don't forget to set the reverse_cost if needed.

Comment: If I set also the reverse_cost in this way I have no information if a street is one-way or not!!

Comment: Ok. I solved it. I didn't know that I can used the if condition in sql. Thanks

Comment: Why "if"? Just UPDATE <table> SET reverse_cost=km WHERE reverse_cost < 1000000